# how to subset data frame to contain all elements that contain a certain word

Tags: r, string, dataframe, extract

[image: data frame]

I want to subset my data frame to contain all elements that contain the word 'inhibitor'. I want to keep the entire element. For example, I'd have a new data frame with:
342 RENIN INHIBITORS,
342 RENIN INHIBITORS,
216 ALPHA-GLUCOSIDASE INHIBITORS,
etc.

This doesn't work

```
library(dplyr)
TC1S1 = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/TC1S1.csv')
x <- TC1S1 %>% filter(grepl('inhibitor', TC1S1[,1]))
```

Comment: We cannot read data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(h)`, if that is not too large.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply()` in row mode along with `grepl()`, for a base R option:

```r
a[apply(a, 1, function(r) any(grepl("inhibitor", r, fixed=TRUE))), ]

  col1            col2            col3
1 drug  drug-inhibitor drug inhibitor3
2 drug drug inhibitor2 drug inhibitor4
```

**Data:**

```
a <- data.frame(col1=c('drug', 'drug', 'drug'),
                col2=c('drug-inhibitor', 'drug inhibitor2', 'drug'),
                col3=c('drug inhibitor3', 'drug inhibitor4', 'drug'))
```

Comment: Darn. this did not work on my data set. it made them all blank. Let me try to add the actual data.

Comment: I just added the actual data set.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `str_detect()`, e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
a <- data.frame(
  col1 = c("drug", "drug", "drug"),
  col2 = c("drug-inhibitor", "drug inhibitor2", "drug"),
  col3 = c("drug inhibitor3", "drug inhibitor4", "drug")
)

a %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ stringr::str_detect(string = ., pattern = "inhibitor")))
```

Output:

```
  col1            col2            col3
1 drug  drug-inhibitor drug inhibitor3
2 drug drug inhibitor2 drug inhibitor4
```